# Why does the Tint of searchbar in UISearchDisplayController looks different than the tint for normal searchbar?

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar

This is what happen without settings. Notice that both tint is null. However they look different.

I kind of like the whitish one on top though I cannot change the rest to that. The searchBar.tint is nil in all cases.

[image]

Update: it must have something to do with the misterious UISearchBarBackground class.

This is what happen if I remove them.

[image]

(I remove code that set UITextFieldBackground so all of you can see that it's all part of apple stuff)

Comment: +1, this is a great find.  I would open a bug report with apple.

Comment: Dude, I am very surprised it's a bug. It's so common and it's so obvious. Anyone can easily do this. Oh ya, this would happen even if I do not change the UITextfield background image.

Comment: Well, it beats me as to why they wouldn't be more consistent.  Also, bug reports aren't just for bugs, you know.  Enhancements, tweaks, nuances, complaints, all get filed daily.

Comment: The reason is actually because behind that background bar there is a misterious segment control. The tint for searchdisplay controller is really just the background image of that segment control.